# Tcl logger package - bug when inheriting logproc

Tags: logging, tcl

Consider the following code:

```
package require logger
proc mylog {msg} {
    puts "mylog: $msg"
}
set p [logger::init parent]
set c [logger::init parent::child]
${p}::logproc error mylog
${p}::error "from parent"
${c}::error "from child"
```

Resulting output:

```
mylog: from parent
mylog: -_logger::service parent::child {from child}
```

So, changing logproc for a parent kinda propagates to a child logger, but produces a bug. I can workaround the issue by setting the logproc for the child explicitly. Is it a genuine bug or am I overlooking something? I believed, this was the standard Tcl package for logging. Should I drop this package altogether and switch to something else?

Answer (score 0):

Using tcllib's `logger` package in version `0.9.4` (most current), I can reproduce the inflated argument passed to your custom proc `mylog`. The two-arguments form of the `logproc` does not provide for massaging (internally)  the arguments list before passing it down to your proc in case of "inheritance".

One immediate option for you: Use the old, three-arguments form of `logproc`:

```
${p}::logproc error msg {
  puts "mylog: $msg"
}
```

---

> I believed, this was the standard Tcl package for logging.

It comes with tcllib and is maintained actively, yes, but I would not call it "standard". If it was, it would be in Tcl core. But there is no logging utility in Tcl core, so there is no standard, simply.

Comment: I will try opening a ticket at https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/ticket later, unless someone else acts first?

Comment: please do, thanks a lot! BTW here I used `logproc` just for the sake of minimal example. My real code uses `logger::utils::applyAppender` (that probably relies on `logproc` under the hood). I find Appender more convenient to apply formatting for all log levels at once. So, the bugfix should be verified with the appender too.

Comment: ok, will check appender too ...